# JPA include additional columns from other tables in a query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have an entity table, which does not associate to another two tables. Now I have a requirement to include also two columns, one from each of these tables, together with my entity in a response/dto.
As there is no association between the tables, I do not want to add the joins in my entity but just a special query. Is there a clean way to do so?

e.g.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id private Integer id;
    @Column private String name;
    @Column private String other;
}

public interface MyEntityRepo extends Repository<MyEntity, Integer> {
    @Query("select a.info, b.desc, m.id, m.name, m.other from MyEntity m join TableA a on m.name = a.name join TableB b on m.name = b.name order by m.id")
    List<MyEntityPlus> findAllPlus();
}
```

I tried using projection to create an interface `MyEntityPlus` like below, but it does not seem to work.

```
public interface MyEntityPlus {
    String getInfo();  // from TableA
    String getDesc();  // from TableB
    Integer getId();   // from MyEntity
    String getName();  // from MyEntity
    String getOther(); // from MyEntity
}
```

Comment: It should be fine if you declare your MyEntityPlus as a class and pass the required fields to the constructor call inside the query.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to the question?

Comment: Can you tell us why it didn't work with projection?

Comment: There is no exception, I did get the correct number of objects in the returned `List`, just that the methods like `getInfo()` `getName()` returns null.